# $().attr(...) is undefined Halfway Through a Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

So I'm using FullCalendar (version 3, as it was part of a template), and trying to get the JSON feed setup properly, and in doing so, had changed the file structure of my files a bit.  The problem that I encountered is that, halfway through FullCalendar's `eventRender` callback, jQuery suddenly craps out with `el.attr(...) is undefined`.  Here's my calendar function:

```js
$("#empCal").fullCalendar({
 height: "auto",
 timeZone: "UTC",
 header: {
  left: "prev,next today",
  center: "title",
  right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek"
 },
 displayEventEnd: true,
 events:[
  {
   title: "Worked",
   start: "2019-09-29T08:00:32",
   end: "2019-09-29T16:29:56",
   className: "event-one",
   props: {
    clock1: "08:00:32",
    clock2: "12:29:56",
    clock3: "13:00:11",
    clockLast: "16:29:56",
    break1: "00:30:15",
    hours: "07:59:09",
    date: "2019-07-29",
    type: "worked"
   }
  }
 ],
 eventRender: function(event, element) {
  let el = $(element);
  console.log(el);
  for(var i in event.props) {
   el.attr(i, event.props[i]);
  }
  el.addClass("cal-period-gray");
  let day = parseInt(el.attr("data-date").substring(8));
  let curDay = new Date().getDay();
  if(0 < curDay <= 15)
   if(0 < day <= 15)
    el.removeClass("cal-period-gray");
 },
 eventClick: function(event, el) {
  popup(event);
 }
});
```

Now, up until the line `let day = parseInt(el.attr("data-date").substring(8));`, el works just fine as a jQuery object (I can see in my DOM that the attributes added with `el.attr(i, event.props[i]);` are actually on the element), but suddenly, at that other line, it gives me the undefined error.  What could cause jQuery to stop working in the middle of a function like that?  And it was working just fine before I started refactoring my file structure to allow for the JSON feed, and I haven't even implemented it yet, but there were too many changes, and I can't revert to try to find the change that went wrong.

Comment: What **exactly** is the error message? Take a screenshot of your console if you can't convey it properly in text

Comment: I'm guessing the actual error message is meant to be interpreted as something like `The value returned by el.attr("data-date") is undefined.`

Comment: [_"As of jQuery 1.6, the `.attr()` method returns `undefined` for attributes that have not been set."_](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1)

Comment: Ugh, I feel so stupid.  This is why you shouldn't post questions at the end of the night.  I was looking at the wrong element to find `data-date`.  It was there, just a couple of parents up the tree...